# Generate rsa keypair client-side on the browser

Tags: browser, pki

I'm not very expert in this kind of programming, and I know there is several similar questions, but anyone answered exactly that I need.

My team (and I) are developing a Public Key Infrastructure. We are stuck in the key generation (on client side), but we found so few documentation about it.

We know there are these options:

keygen tag --> generates a SPKAC request --> works in Mozilla to internal keystore, token and smartcard

crypto.generateCRMFRequest() --> generates a CRMF Request --> works in Mozilla to internal keystore, token and smartcard

CryptoAPI, CAPI, XEnroll CEnroll --> generates a CSR PKCS#10 (I think so) --> Works in Internet Explorer (we still haven't found code's examples)

Javascript or java Applet (yes I know, both are different) generates in all with sunpkcs11, bouncycastle or iaik API (can't reach any goal)

We found this options. but we don't know how to get the results, how to create to a CSR PKCS#10 request and how to handle it.

please, could you give me an advice about select the strategy, find how to implement and handle results, convert results and so? we are getting crazy!

Example: we know how to use the keygen tag, but we don't know how to set the key to only RSA 2048, and how to handle the SPKAC request to convert in a good CSR signed on SHA256

We tried to develop a Java Applet with iaik API, but the CSR generated had an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out, SPKAC is not broadly supported (even by CAs), it would be better if viable for your case to use PKCS10 in all browsers.

Here is an example doing that - https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/csrhelp

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on all counts, as far as using browser tags to generate the keypair and/or certificate request.  I recommend you take a look at the Odyssi CS project on Sourceforge.  It's a very simple CA implementation written in Java/JSP.  Take a look at the JSP files and you can see how the various options are being passed to the key generation tags.

Basically, you generate the keypair as part of a form submission.  From there, they're available in the same way as any other request parameter.  You'll need to know how to decode them on the backend.  IE generates the request as a PKCS#10, which is nice since it's a well-documented standard.  The SPKAC format isn't as widely used, but there are still good documentation and libraries available.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/odyssipki/

Comment: Thanks for answer this issue. I'm downloading this right now. I will try it and soon I will post comments here

Comment: I put the source in Netbeans, and I couldn't make it run properly, but I have followed the code (trying to understand the processes) and I'm making a sample class to make the same. It's usefull, but still I have troubles. When I reach an complete solution, I will post it here